# Recursive function solving

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, settimeout

Not sure why when this is ran it prints both of the dot's in the array at the same time. Why does it not print dot pause then print dash then dot. Is my conditional written wrong?

```js
function morseCode(code) {
  if (code.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  let ele = code[code.length - 1];
  if (ele === "dot") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("dot");
    }, 100);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("dash");
    }, 300);
  }
  return morseCode(code.slice(0, -1));
}
let code = ["dot", "dash", "dot"];

morseCode(code);
// print 'dot'
// pause for 100ms
// print 'dash'
// pause for 300ms
// print 'dot'
// pause for 100ms
```

Comment: You've set three timers at basically the same time, two for 100ms and one for 300ms, so the two 100ms timers (dots) finish and print, then 100ms later the 300ms timer finishes. If you want to pause, you need to call `morseCode()` with the sliced array inside the timer.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not "pause" the code execution.  What it does is... it pushes the function you pass it onto the "stack" with the timeout value given.  Then once your function is done running, the browser will then go to this "stack" (which my also contain browser UI code) and run the function in the future when their timeouts hit.  You have 2 timeouts at 100ms and 1 at 300ms.  Note that the code may not run at *exactly* 100ms.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout isn't blocking your execution. So you queue up three functions pretty much at the same time with the same interval: (dot in 100ms), (dash in 300ms), (dot in 100ms)

You see after 100ms you print dot two times, after 300ms you print dash one time.

Answer (score 1):

try to put `return morseCode(code.slice(0, -1));` inside the `setTimeout`, `setTimeout` is non-blocking, if you want to achieve what you want, you need to call `morseCode` inside `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it:

```js
let code = '...-..---..-..--.---'
  .split('')
  .map(char => char === '.' ? 'dot' : 'dash');

function morse(arr){
  const word = arr.shift();
  const delay = word === 'dot' ? 100 : 500;

  console.log(word);

  if (arr.length) {
    setTimeout(morse, delay, arr);
  }  
}

morse(code);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

It is important to start the "next" letter from *inside* the timeout callback function, as otherwise all [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#syntax) calls will be timed from the same point in time.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSeliger for beautifying my answer. I usually write very terse as I like to read everything on one page, but this is probably more amenable for the majority of readers. Thanks also for the hint with the third argument in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Hey, but here comes another question: Why do you think is it important to use `===`here instead of `==`? Won't the shorter form (`==`) also *reliably* always get the same result?

Comment: since I like the approach very much, the intension was not to correct you, but make the code more comprehensive for beginners, thus also featuring strict equality for getting used to lint'ed code even though it was not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The call of the function doesn't have timeout, try this:

```
function morseCode(code) {
        let time = 0
        if (code.length === 0) {
          return;
        }
        let ele = code[code.length - 1];
        if (ele === "dot") {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("dot");
          }, 100);
          time = 100
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("dash");
          }, 300);
          time = 300
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          return morseCode(code.slice(0, -1));
          }, time);
        
      }
      let code = ["dot", "dash", "dot"];

      morseCode(code);
```

Hope that could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple recursive way to write this:

```js
const morse = ([c, ...cs]) => 
  c !== undefined &&
  setTimeout (() => morse (cs), c == '.' ? 100 : c == '-' ? 500 : 1000) &&
  console .log (c == '.' ? 'dot' : c == '-' ? 'dash' : '')  

morse ('.... . .-.. .-.. ---')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We destructure the parameter containing a string of characters.  If the first one doesn't exist, then we quit.  If it does, we set a timeout to run this again with the remaining characters, the delay determined by the character, then we log the 'dot'/'dash'/blank character matching the current value.

If that style isn't to your liking, this is equivalent:

```js
const morse = ([c, ...cs]) => {
  if (c !== undefined) {
    const char = c == '.' ? 'dot' : c == '-' ? 'dash' : ''
    const delay = c == '.' ? 100 : c == '-' ? 400 : 800
    setTimeout (() => morse (cs), delay)
    console .log (char)  
  }
}
```